# Getting input parameter names for operations provided in WSDL file | SOAP | Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm trying to read all the parameters required for sending a soap request, a sample wsdl which I'm trying to read is of following type:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="some url">
....
<xs:element name="Bin">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="BinParameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
....
<xs:element name="CartAdd">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MarketplaceDomain" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="AssociateTag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Request" type="tns:CartAddRequest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
....
```

I'm using following code to get the list of operations available:

```
URL wsdlURL =new URL("https://<some soap url>/sample.wsdl");
WSDLReader reader = WSDLUtil.newWSDLReaderWithPopulatedExtensionRegistry();
definition = reader.readWSDL(wsdlURL.toString());
Map<QName, PortType> portTypes = definition.getAllPortTypes();
for (QName key : portTypes.keySet()) {
    List<Operation> operations = portTypes.get(key).getOperations();
    for (Operation operation : operations) {
        Map col = operation.getInput().getMessage().getParts();
    }
}
```

WSDLUtil used is from "org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLUtil", Using above code we're able to get all operations available(like "CartAdd"), How can we get all the parameters required for the given operation(in this case "MarketplaceDomain", "AssociateTag" etc.) ? Any sample code or reference would help.